# Sorting records based on Newsequentialid()

Tags: sql-server

Is it safe/reliable to sort a record (from the oldest to the newest) based on their Id (GUID type) if the GUID is created using Newsequentialid() in SQL Server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, because [`NEWSEQUENTIALID()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189786.aspx) is only guaranteed to be generated in increasing order until the server is restarted:

> Creates a GUID that is greater than any GUID previously generated by
>   this function on a specified computer since Windows was started. After
>   restarting Windows, the GUID can start again from a lower range, but
>   is still globally unique.

Since you can't guarantee that the sever will **never** restart you can't rely on this to always create ascending values based on creation date.

Comment: how about newsequentialid()?